# How long does it take to create an OCFS2 filesystem on a 1TB disk?

Tags: storage, amazon-ebs, drbd, ocfs2

I'm creating an OCFS2 fs for use with DRBD and it's taking an awful long time to create the filesystem.

I haven't done it before so I'm wondering if someone with more experience can relate how long it should actually take? I googled but strangely couldn't find anything on this.

The underlying disk is 2x500GB EBS volumes over LVM.

It's been running for about 1hr15 mins now.

My I/O wait is staying steady at 48-52% and mkfs is in the D+ state. I don't know if its actually doing anything or if its hung.

I cancelled it before (after about 15 mins) and tried again because I assumed it had hung, so its not a once-off problem.

Here's the output:

```
mkfs.ocfs2 1.4.3
Cluster stack: classic o2cb
Filesystem label=
Block size=4096 (bits=12)
Cluster size=4096 (bits=12)
Volume size=1073700630528 (262133943 clusters) (262133943 blocks)
8127 cluster groups (tail covers 21687 clusters, rest cover 32256 clusters)
Journal size=268435456
Initial number of node slots: 8
Creating bitmaps: done
Initializing superblock: done
Writing system files:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seconds to create the actual FS, literally seconds - something is very wrong. Try it on the base individual disks first just to see how that goes and come back ok.

Comment: Aha! It works on the base disks pretty quickly, but then trying it on an LVM device (even without using the DRBD device) exhibits the hanging behavior. I had thought it was fine to use OCFS2 over LVM but perhaps not.